# how to force a cucumber scenario to fail?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

Is there a way to force a cucumber scenario to fail?

I need to check for a few failing scenarios at the end of each of my tests. So I thought I could do the check for an 'error' dialog and then fail the test if it occurred.

This is possible with the code below however there is a problem. Once I raise the exception in the fail! function, then cucumber stops running the rest of the After hook, so the logout function doesnt get called.

Was:

```
After() do |scenario|  
  #Checking for Error popups
  if page.has_selector?(:dialog_message, 1, :text => 'Error')
    fail!(raise(ArgumentError.new('Unexpected Error dialog!')))
  end
  logout
end
```

Now:

```
After() do |scenario|  
  #Checking for Error popups
  if page.has_selector?(:dialog_message, 1, :text => 'Error')
    scenario.fail!(logout)
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to fail a cucumber test without raising an exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the after hook to fail using your normal assertions. Have not done much with Capybara/rspec exceptions, but I think you can do:

```
page.should have_selector?(:dialog_message, 1, :text => 'Error')
```

However, if you do this or do the scenario.fail!(), you will still not logout. You need to wrap it in a begin-ensure block.

Try this:

```
After do |scenario|
    begin
        page.should have_selector?(:dialog_message, 1, :text => 'Error')
    ensure
        logout
    end
end
```

**Update**

If you do not want to call the standard assertions and directly fail the scenario, you can do the following - you need to use `fail` instead of `fail!`:

```
After() do |scenario|  
  begin 
    #Checking for Error popups
    if page.has_selector?(:dialog_message, 1, :text => 'Error')
      fail(ArgumentError.new('Unexpected Error dialog!'))
      #Or you can just do fail('Unexpected Error dialog') if you do not care about the type.
    end
  ensure
    logout
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, I never thought about using the ensure block. I was hoping there would be a way of getting the scenario to fail without raising an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Just a preliminary answer as I haven't been able to check it out yet, but I'd assume that calling `Raise` is always guaranteed to halt execution (unless it's done inside a proc or lambda so it's evaluation is deferred).

Try simply

```
if page.has_selector?(:dialog_message, 1, :text => 'Error')
    scenario.fail!(StandardError.new('Unexpected Error Dialog!'))
end
logout
```

Comment: Sorry, try `scenario.fail!('message')`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that there too.
I got the error:
   undefined method `message' for "message":String (NoMethodError)

So I tried this:
   scenario.fail!(logout)

This half worked. At least it ran my logout code and failed the test, but it still gave an error message:
   undefined method `message' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: I'm a bit confused where that could be coming from - could you update the question with the current code that's causing that error?

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your edit - `scenario.fail!` expects an exception object to be supplied, so passing in your `logout` method seems to have evaluated to `nil` which is why it's complaining.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jon, The logout method isnt getting called once the fail or fail! method is called. 
I just used Justin Ko's second solution. So it seems you have to use an ensure block to make sure the logout function is called.