# Modifying a cucumber step definition to give more useful output

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rspec2

wrote a step definition that checks CSS elements using rspec in a collection. If one expectation fails the whole scenario bombs and I don't even get unique feedback on whether each CSS element exists or not (it's all or nothing, unfortunately! I don't want that)

I have the following code:

```
Then(/^I should see the following css selectors:$/) do |table|
  css_selectors = table.raw
  css_selectors.each do |selector|
    browser.element(:css=>selector.to_s).exists?.should be_true
  end
end
```

If I test a big list of elements, i.e.:

```
Then I should see the following css selectors:
  |input#foo|
  |.bar     |
  |h#baz    |
  |span.batz|
```

I'll have problems if any element doesn't exist. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a customized message to the failure that includes the selector that failed. This is done by passing a second argument to the `should` method:

```
Then(/^I should see the following css selectors:$/) do |table|
  css_selectors = table.raw
  css_selectors.each do |selector|
    css_selector = selector[0].to_s
    browser.element(:css=>css_selector).exists?.should be_true, "Element not found: #{css_selector}"
  end
end
```

This would give an error message like:

```
Element not found: input#foo (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

If you also want to ensure that all selectors are run, you will have to run each one, collect the results and perform an assertion on the group of results.

```
Then(/^I should see the following css selectors:$/) do |table|
  css_selectors = table.raw

  # Collect any failed selectors
  failed_selectors = []
  css_selectors.each do |selector|
    css_selector = selector[0].to_s
    failed_selectors << css_selector unless browser.element(:css=>css_selector).exists?
  end

  # Check that none of the selectors failed
  failed_selectors.should be_empty, "The following elements were not found #{failed_selectors.join(', ')}"
end
```

Comment: hmm. tried it. didn't quite work. looking at it some more. that looks like a great solution, and I do remember learning about that when I was reading up on rspec

Comment: Try the updated answer. I think the problem is the `selector.to_s` is returning `[input#foo]`, which would mess up your selector. You need to do the extra `[0]` to get the first element of the table row. If that's not it, can you please elaborate on "didn't work".

Comment: That did it. still, if ` |input#foo|` isn't present, it doesn't check for `|.bar     |
  |h#baz    |
  |span.batz|`

Comment: Sorry, did not realize you also wanted to ensure that all selectors were tested. Answer updated for a way to ensure that all selectors are tested.

Comment: That was awesome. Thanks Justin!

Answer (score 0):

can you not call `fail` on the scenario?

see: [how to force a cucumber scenario to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797171/how-to-force-a-cucumber-scenario-to-fail)