# verify text in selenium ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I have an issue with verifying text in selenium webdriver and Ruby.

Aim: Verify that the sentence 'Registration Form' is valid on the website.

I have the below code:

```
if /registration Form/.match(driver.page_source)
    puts "Test Passed".green

else 
    puts "Test Failed".red
end
```

This code will output "Test Failed" even though the text is present. I have noticed if I only search for one word E.G. 'Registration' the test will pass, but my code needs to check for more than one word.

**Additional question:**
In addition, this may be a rather simple question to answer, but even when my test fails with "Test Failed" in Cucumber, my result is actually passed. Does anyone know how I could get the actual Cucumber test to fail via an extra line of code?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I haven't done selenium ruby in a long time so I'm not sure I can help. Have you tried putting single or double quotes around `resigration Form`?

Comment: see here for how to fail a cucumber step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797171/how-to-force-a-cucumber-scenario-to-fail